# services not getting called defined in ngOnInit in angular9?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have a component and in the ngOnInit() ,I have 2 services to which I have subscribed.

MY issue is that when I reload the page,one of the services is getting called correctly,but dont know why one of the service is getting skipped and executing after some more actions.Can nanyone help on this?

```
ngOnInit() {
this._service1.getItem().subscribe((data)=>{
store.dispatch(actionCreators.action1({payload:data}))
}

)

this._service2.getFRuits().subscribe((data)=>{
........
})
```

}

service 1 is getting skipped while reloading but service 2 is going fine.Can anyone help why>
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the component code please, to better understand the context ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Calling subscribe() simply creates an observable. In your example, you should expect ngOnInit() to run to the end and the code within subscribe to run once the data has been returned from the service.

To see this in action, I would recommend using console.log() to see execution order.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('start ngOnInit')
    this._service1.getItem().subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('retrieve _service1.getItem()')
            store.dispatch(actionCreators.action1({
                payload: data
            }))
        }

    )

    this._service2.getFRuits().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('retrieve _service2.getFRuits()')
            ........
    })
    console.log('finish ngOnInit')
}
```

Console output:

```
'start ngOnInit'
'finish ngOnInit'
'retrieve _service1.getItem()'
'retrieve _service2.getFRuits()'
```

Or if service1 runs slower than service2:

```
'start ngOnInit'
'finish ngOnInit'
'retrieve _service2.getFRuits()'
'retrieve _service1.getItem()'
```

If this._service1.getItem().subscribe((data) never returns data or behaves inconstantly, then that's usually an issue with the service or the injection.